# A method that iterates over the passed in objects properties

Tags: c#, oop, reflection

Trying to figure out how to create a method that will iterate over the properties of an object, and output them (say console.writeline for now).

Is this possible using reflection?

e.g.

```
public void OutputProperties(object o)
{

      // loop through all properties and output the values

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try the following

```
public void OutputProperties(object o) {
  if ( o == null ) { throw new ArgumentNullException(); }
  foreach ( var prop in o.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance) ) {
    var value = prop.GetValue(o,null);
    Console.WriteLine("{0}={1}", prop.Name, value);
  }
}
```

This will output all properties declared on the specific type.  It will fail if any of the properties throw an exception when evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative using `TypeDescriptor`, allowing custom object models to show flexible properties at runtime (i.e. what you see can be more than just what is on the class, and can use custom type-converters to do the string conversion):

```
public static void OutputProperties(object obj)
{
    if (obj == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("obj");
    foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(obj))
    {
        object val = prop.GetValue(obj);
        string s = prop.Converter.ConvertToString(val);
        Console.WriteLine(prop.Name + ": " + s);
    }
}
```

Note that reflection is the *default* implementation - but many other more interesting models are possible, via `ICustomTypeDescriptor` and `TypeDescriptionProvider`.

Comment: internally aren't they using reflection?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could use

```
foreach (var objProperty in o.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    Console.WriteLine(objProperty.Name + ": " + objProperty.GetValue(o, null));
}
```